# Como resuelvo este error: Failed to read row 0, column 20 from a CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 4 columns

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Es para Android Studio, agrego mi código del cursor para ser mas específicos.

```
public ArrayList<Work> obtenDatos(){
        Cursor datos = dataBaseWorks.getTareas();
        ArrayList<Work> tareas = new ArrayList<Work>();
        try {
            while (datos.moveToNext()) {
                String name = datos.getString(datos.getInt(0));
                String date = datos.getString(datos.getInt(1));
                String desc = datos.getString(datos.getInt(2));

                Work work = new Work(name, date, desc);

                tareas.add(work);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return tareas;
    }
```

Esta conectado a una base de datos en SQLite, donde tiene una única tabla llamada Tarea y tiene cuatro columnas, id_tarea, nombre, fecha, descripción pero me arroja este error Failed to read row 0, column 20 from a CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 4 columns, igual ya intente con String name = datos.getString(datos.getColumnIndex("nombre"); y da otro error que el cursor esta definiendo columnas negativas.

Comment: La consulta es incorrecta, no tiene los campos que tratas de consultar del cursor.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error indica el problema, en español es:

> No se pudo leer la fila 0, columna 20 de un CursorWindow que tiene 5
> filas, 4 columnas, igual que la intención con String name =
> datos.getString(datos.getColumnIndex("nombre");

**El problema es que tratas de leer un valor que no existe en el cursor, ya que trata de leer la primera fila (row 0) el campo con índice 20 y tu cursor ùnicamente tiene 5 filas y 4 columnas**

Si esto no funciona,

> String name = datos.getString(datos.getColumnIndex("nombre");

indica que tu consulta no tiene el campo "nombre", confirmando lo antes expuesto.

---

El còdigo que expones indica el error "y da otro error que el cursor esta definiendo columnas negativas.", esto significa que la consulta no obtiene los datos necesarios.

En ambos casos revisa la consulta.